# SQL Query to list all tables+columns in a specific database/server?

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

I have lots of servers ranging from ABC001 to ABC100, and each one has 100+ companies under it, each company with 100+ tables under it. I want to select a specific server (i.e. ABC005) to get the list of all tables from. I don't wanna get that list for literally everything from ABC001 to ABC100.

I know I can pull it with

```
Select * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

But is there a way to point to a specific server/DB so that I can save resources and time?

Should it be FROM ABC005.dbo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS for example?

Comment: It should work across databases but not across instances unless you have the respective linked servers.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to hit a specific server.  Adding the DB name before `ABC005.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` (no `.dbo.`) works.  But I find the data returned from the following query to be a bit easier to read:

```
select t.name
      ,c.name
      ,st.name as system_type
      ,c.max_length
      ,c.precision
      ,c.scale
      ,d.definition
      ,c.is_nullable
      ,c.is_rowguidcol
      ,c.is_filestream
from   ABC005.sys.tables t 
       inner join ABC005.sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
       inner join ABC005.sys.types st on c.system_type_id = st.user_type_id
       left outer join ABC005.sys.default_constraints d on c.default_object_id = d.object_id
where  t.type = 'U'
order by t.name, c.column_id
```

Comment: If the servers are numbered sequentially, or if you have a list of servers in a separate file, I would write the sql in a separate file and would write a batchfile around it.  If they are sequential you'd just loop around echo'ing the results to a text file.

Comment: @drHodge - Good suggestion, using `SQLCMD` and specifying the server name on the command line.